# <! --nextpage--> pagination is not working in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, pagination

I'm trying to make it so posts can be easily paginated in a custom theme, but I'm doing something wrong. I've included wp_link_pages(); in the while like which I believe is required, but maybe I have it in the wrong place or I'm missing something else?

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php  

while(have_posts()) {
    the_post();
    wp_link_pages();

?>
  <div class="mainConent">
    <div class="leftSidebar">
        <div class="sidebarTitleWrapper">
          <?php dynamic_sidebar('left_sidebar') ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="recentBlogsWrapper">
    <div class="blogWrapper">
      <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
      <p><?php the_time('F j, Y') ?></p>
      <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()) { ?>
          <div class="card-image">
              <img class="page-image" src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID()); ?>" alt="Card Image">
          </div>
      <?php } ?>
      <div class="card-description">
        <?php the_content(); ?>
        <?php comments_template(); ?>
        <?php } ?>
        <div class="backarrowwrap">
          <a class="backhomelink" href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>" <?php if(is_front_page()) echo 'class="active"' ?>>
            <img class="backarrow" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/backarrow.png" alt="back arrow" />
            Go Back Home
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rightSidebar" id="sidebar">
        <div class="sidebarTitleWrapper">
          <?php dynamic_sidebar('right_sidebar') ?>
        </div>
    </div>




<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Another odd thing that's happening is that the code block is showing the code on the page instead of hiding it like it should.

The wordpress editor

[image: wordpress blog editor]

My blog post page which shows the code

[image: wordpress blog post page]

Comment: Hi, Php scripts not works in wordpress post editor for this you need to use plugin that why  php script tags are showing on page

Comment: I included it in the link there as a test, I didn't think it would work like that. It's in the code as well and still doesn't work.

Comment: Try This  ,
wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-link-next-prev">',
 'after' => '</div>', 'next_or_number' => 'next', 'previouspagelink' =>
 __('Previous'), 'nextpagelink'=> __('Next')  ) );

Comment: Couldn't get that to work.

Comment: I just figured out that the Gutenburg editor is why my code is on the pages, it's displaying it as regular content instead of code like it says. I switched to the classic view and now it's half working. The rest of the page is disappearing but no pagination links are showing up.

Answer (score 0):

Gutenburg was preventing me from writing the comment as code, even in a code box. Once I switched to the classic view the problem went away since I could write the  comment in the html directly.